# Ubuntu details show ubuntu14.10 but I have 15.04. Also can't update softwares

Tags: ubuntu

I did some configuration file changes I don't remember and now details show I have ubuntu 14.10 on base version 15.04. Also I can't update the system and each time it asks me to update to 14.10. No idea which file I changed. Can you guys help me out on this. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see `lsb_release -a` output,

and config file `/etc/lsb-release`

ref: `/usr/share/doc/lsb-release/README.Debian`